# How long does a trailhead playground org last?

Tags: sandbox, trailhead

When I go to trailhead I have a "Hands-On Orgs" option under my profile picture. How long does an org created through that menu last?

**Screenshot of the menu**

[image]

**Screenshot when creating a new playground through the menu**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The life span is 6 months if there is no activity, if you working on it then it will not expire.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? How do you know this?

Comment: @Arthlete it's not documented yet, I am a salesforce employee and checked internally.

Comment: In this case thank you for unveiling this for us :)

Answer (score 0):

it not being documented but it last forever until you are not decoupling it from your trailhead orgs.